# context isolation when loading local content

Tags: electron

I've read the electron security policy docs (https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security) and the new default values set for the upcoming electron 5.x (https://electronjs.org/blog/electron-4-0) and couldn't figure out if contextIsolation is needed when loading local web content (local index.html).

I understand the need for it when loading remote content, but is it really necessary when loading local content?
If so, how should the bridge api configured in the preload script between the main and renderer process should be used in order to expose the API on the renderer process's Window object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a security expert, but in my view, you don't get much benefit from turning on context isolation if you're never loading external content.

The whole point of that flag is to run your preload script in an isolated JavaScript environment, so it's not affected by any changes, malicious or otherwise, that a page can make to JavaScript globals or object prototypes.

For example, if my external page overwrites `Date.now`:

```
Date.now = () => return 1;
```

And your preload script, or an Electron API that you're calling is calling `Date.now()`, then it will use the overwritten version instead of the original function.

The `contextIsolation` flag mitigates against this type of attack.

Electron [says](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#3-enable-context-isolation-for-remote-content) themselves (emphasis added):

> Enable Context Isolation for **Remote Content**

So no, you don't need it for local content.

Comment: this is what I understood as well from the docs and I wanted to confirm that. According to: https://electronjs.org/blog/electron-4-0 in Electron 5 the default values for nodeIntegration and contextIsolation will be changed to false and true respectively so I wanted to see that I'm not missing something...

Comment: @AvnerHoffmann Yeah they're just changing all the defaults so that electron apps are more secure by default, but in your case, you don't need the context isolation flag enabled

Answer (score 2):

@pushkin's answer neglects consideration for any modules you might be loading. unless you trust the code in said modules, context isolation still has benefits for a local content-only electron app.

Comment: And also user generated data can be a danger.